# ASP.NET Core Extension Method to convert Enum to SelectList

Tags: asp.net-core, generics, enums, extension-methods, selectlist

I tried to write a generic extension method for Enums, I was unsuccessful, each extension methods gets an enum Item not enum List

```
public static SelectList GetSelectList<TEnum>(this IQueryable<TEnum> source, bool indexed = false) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    return new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>().Select(item => new SelectListItem
    {
       Text = "Foo",
       Value = indexed ? "Bar" : "Biz"
    }).ToList(), "Value", "Text");
}
```

ex:

```
public enum EnumName
{
    Item1=1,
    Item1=2,
}
```

It applies to **Item1** but I want to use it like **EnumName.GetSelectList(true)**.
It works fine as **Function** but I need to implement it as a **Generic Extension Method**!

Comment: Why do you need your own extension method? You can use this: `Html.GetEnumSelectList<EnumName>()`

Comment: _“each extension methods gets an enum Item not enum List”_ – What do you mean with that? And why does your method always set a fixed `Text` and `Value`? And what is `indexed` is supposed to mean?

Comment: @poke The method is example, It runs process, I skipped the process.  Is there anyway to apply extension methods on enum list rather than enum item?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I don't have access to Html in .cs methods